# How can I save a write protected file in vi?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to save my modified "menu.lst" file in vi. When I save the file, vi says: `'menu.lst' is read only`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `sudo` to edit the file. You can use `sudo -e menu.lst` (instead of `vi menu.lst`) to open the file using the default editor, but that might be something other than `vi` on your system. You can also just use `sudo vi menu.lst` to edit the file using `vi` as the root user.

Answer (score 2):

The file you are trying to save is read-only, meaning you cannot modify its contents. It needs to be marked as writable. The process varies depending on your OS. Here are some helpful resources on how to change permissions of files:

- For Windows 10: [Nibbleguru: How to remove read-only attribute in Windows 10](https://www.nibbleguru.com/67_remove-read-only-attribute-windows-10/)
- For Linux (using chmod): [TLDP: File Permissions](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x9543.htm)
- For macOS: [Chron: How to Change File Permission From Read-Only to Read-Write on a Mac](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-file-permission-readonly-readwrite-mac-67960.html)

**EDIT:**
As filbranden pointed out, for Grub's files, you should be opening vi using the `sudo` command. Grub's files are meant to be modified by root only. You should be opening your files using `sudo vi menu.lst` instead.

Comment: Tnx bro, i tried it on the grub menu / Android x86

Comment: Changing permissions of the file is not always the right approach. In this case, it definitely isn't. The files owned by GRUB are meant to be writable by the root user only. You're supposed to use `sudo` or similar to edit them.

Comment: @filbranden Oh yea for something like GRUB, `sudo` would be the command you need to use. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I have this on my vimrc

```
cnoremap w!! execute 'silent! write !sudo tee % >/dev/null' <bar> edit!
command! SaveAsRoot w !sudo tee %
cnoreabbrev sudow SaveAsRoot
```

For instant use, just copy to the clipboard and run:

```
:@+
:SaveAsRoot
```

The `:@+` loads your clipboard into vim memory which allows you to run the given commands while not saved on your vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

People suggest using `sudo vi(m)` on unix, but this could have unwanted consequences: all commands executed in this window are done by `root` and so you could accidentally do unwanted things like deleting file or just creating files owned by `root`.

Instead you should think about using `sudoedit` instead. It will copy the file to `/tmp` and open it in `$EDITOR` (if you are using vim, you should set it in your `~/.profile` / `~/.bash_profile`).

But beware: Something I stumbled across: the original file is only replaced when you close vim - no matter how often you save! (This is, because you are editing the file in `/tmp` and not the original).

It is not that I don't use `sudo vim` but if I do, I am extra cautious about what I do ;) I do it for example if I know that I will need to edit multiple files as root, or that I want to execute other commands from within vim as root (e.g. `git`)

And something even more important to me: `sudo vim` is using `root`s `vimrc` instead of mine, but with `sudoedit` I have my own config...

Comment: Thanks for going into all the details! The reason why saving many times doesn't overwrite the original file is because `sudoedit` will make a copy of it in some temporary directory, then you edit it as non-root and finally it copies it back into the original location (I guess you know that, just you might want to explain that here too.) You might want to mention that `sudo -e` is equivalent to `sudoedit`. I think these days most Linux/Unix distributions include a `sudoedit`, but in case they don't, `sudo -e` might work (well, if it's recent enough.) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @filbranden! I added a short explenation. And yes, I went into some details because when I first read about this, it just said "always use sudoedit instead of sudo vim" and it took me quite some time to figure out why...